Thingsboard report mismatch sender Id using FCM
We have been working on implementing push notifications in our IoT-based application using Thingsboard notification (Thingsboard version 3.6.3)  and Firebase for a month. We are using Android Studio and Flutter framework.
First, we tried the Thingsboard flutter application to test this feature and all things were going very well but when we decided to use this feature on our flutter application we received "Sender ID mismatch" error on Thingsboard.
It's good to mention that we can send notifications to our app via the Firebase dashboard but we can't send via Thingsbard.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Could you please download the latest version of the Thingsboard Live application from the Apple or Google app store? After downloading, log into https://demo.thingsboard.io and try to send a notification.
Do you see any errors when doing this?

Fortunately, I haven't had any problem with the Thingsboard Flutter application on my server at all. When I switch back to using my application I can't get any notification from my server however I had changed the Firebase token in the sysadmin panel before.
